# Flickering display on Ubuntu 22.04.3 when intense CPU usage

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, graphics, dell, cpu

I am the happy owner of a Dell Precision 5540 with Ubuntu LTS since end 2020. Everything was going perfectly well until 2-3 weeks ago. Now when I have intense CPU usage (data analysis, or Kerbal Space Program for example), first the display lags, then it flickers. This only happens on the integrated display, not the external screen.

I have the nvidia-535 drivers, and my Ubuntu 22.04.3 is up-to-date. Normally, I use the Nvidia "On demand" mode : the integrated display uses the Intel UHD Graphics. I tried to switch to the "Performance" mode with the integrated display on the Nvidia GPU. The problem is then a bit different: the screen goes black during intense CPU usage, without flickering.

I am currently under linux-kernel 6.5. I tried kernel 6.2 with the same issue happening. I do not dare trying with kernels 5.*.

I added the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.enable_dc=0 intel_idle.max_cstate=2
```

to `/etc/default/grub` and admittedly, the problem that used to happen even with a quiet CPU usage is now restrained to intense CPU usage.

However, this is still annoying because I use this laptop for some local computations before moving to larger computing resources. For three years I had absolutely no problem.

If anyone has an idea, I would be very grateful.

**Some edit on Feb. 2nd:**

The problem seems to be related to an overheating of the CPU. Here is the result of the sensors command:

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0: +100.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +96.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +94.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:       +100.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +91.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 4:        +92.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 5:        +91.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

dell_smm-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
fan1:        4335 RPM  (min =    0 RPM, max = 5100 RPM)
fan2:        4330 RPM  (min =    0 RPM, max = 5100 RPM)
temp1:        +98.0°C  
temp2:        +53.0°C  
temp3:        +57.0°C  
temp4:        +61.0°C  
temp5:        +72.0°C  
temp6:        +52.0°C  
temp7:        +38.0°C  
temp8:        +39.0°C  
temp9:        +68.0°C  
temp10:       +70.0°C  

ucsi_source_psy_USBC000:001-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:           5.00 V  (min =  +5.00 V, max =  +5.00 V)
curr1:         0.00 A  (max =  +0.00 A)

BAT0-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:          12.69 V  
curr1:       1000.00 uA 

iwlwifi_1-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +37.0°C  

pch_cannonlake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +46.0°C  

nvme-pci-3d00
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +40.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +82.8°C)
                       (crit = +84.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +40.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
Sensor 2:     +37.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +25.0°C  (crit = +107.0°C)
```

Interestingly, the Dell diagnostics in pre-boot do not detect anything. Could it be that something in Linux now allow the processor to work above some threshold ?

**Update of February 4th:**

The overheating of the processors was caused by

```
intel_idle.max_cstate=2
```

(cf [this table](https://gist.github.com/Brainiarc7/8dfd6bb189b8e6769bb5817421aec6d1)). If I remove it, the CPUs remain below 100°C and the problem is still triggered.

I can have the problem with the TurboBoost enabled and disabled.

An interesting feature: if I changed the screen resolution or wait for it to go in power saving mode when the flickering happens, then the problem stops (even if the CPU is still on intense load).

Comment: might be Hardware issue ? 100 is pretty big number